# SNMP Need to install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, snmp

when i run the command : sudo apt-get install snmpd is giving the following error

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# sudo apt-get install snmpd                             Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic but it is not going to be installed
 snmpd : Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.2~dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libsnmp-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

please give me the solutions to get install snmp service on the sever.

thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you try `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Yes. with -f switch also the result is same.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `uname -r`

Comment: finaly i found this happens because of /Boot partition full. it was partitioned with 100 MB. so the linux images cannot install on the server, due to that the package also not getting installed.

is there any way to increase the "/boot" partition?

Comment: Hi Charles,

output of  "uname -r" is  3.13.0-34-generic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but I've had it happen in a few odd circumstances. An easy way around it is to install every dependency manually. However, since it looks like Apt is having issues resolving dependencies in general, there might be a bigger problem at work here. While I can't help you with that specifically, you can use this to install snmpd:

```
sudo apt-get install snmpd libsnmp30 libsnmp-base
```

If that still gives you linux-image... errors and prevents installation (though, it doesn't look like it should -- that appears to be a different problem) try this:

```
sudo apt-get install snmpd libsnmp30 libsnmp-base linux-image-generic linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic
```